# Exporting Achievements in Gamecenter

Tags: ios, game-center

I am releasing a game for iOS with Game Center integration. I have full and free version and the free version can be upgraded with in-app purchase. I found out the painful and long process of entering all achievements in iTunes connect trough web forms. Questions I have:

- is there no way to export achievements in iTunes connect from one app and import into another?
- why do the same Achievements in both apps have to have different IDs?
- is there no way to change achievement ID once you made a mistake? is the really only way to delete it and start again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group games, so that they can share same list of achievements and leaderboard.  Check for `Move to group` button in gamecenter manage page.

**Edit:** 
The achievements can't be deleted once the app go live, you can create new version of your game to have different achievements, but the older one will be there forever. So either make up your mind while the game is in testing mode or if you really need to change the achievement list, create a whole new game, instead of using versions.

Comment: Edited the answer to include more details